# insert по условию

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

Нужно выполнить insert если в другой таблице есть такой id, стоит ли это делать без связных таблиц? Case или if тут не подойдут предполагаю, писать тригер?

Comment: а причем тут триггер. простой `insert ... select ... from tab where id=x`

Comment: insert into "Tab1" values('hot',3) 
select id_type from "Tab2" where id_type = 1
Если так, то оно не работает.

Comment: ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"

Comment: `insert into Tab1 select 'hot', 3 from Tab2 where id_type=1`

Comment: ну и limit 1 добавить к select есть в tab2 более одной записи с id_type=1. А иначе вставится столько же записей сколько там

Comment: Либо `INSERT .. SELECT`, либо `INSERT .. VALUES`, но не одновременно...